# Google cloud buckets - is there a way to fetch by prefix

Tags: list, google-cloud-storage, bucket, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Storage Buckets has a function to get a paginated listing of the object names inside a bucket, called "list". Here are the docs:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list

If I want to discover whether a certain object name exists, the only (apparent) way to do so is to fetch ALL object names, one page at a time, and look through them myself. This is not scalable.

We have 10,000+ objects stored. So if I want to find gs://mybucket/my/simulated/dir/* or if I want to find gs://mybucket/my/sim*/subdir/*.txt the only way to do so is to retrieve 600,000 bytes of listing information and filter through it with code.

The question: Does anyone know a way, short of keeping track of the object names myself somehow, to get JUST the listings I care about?

Comment: What are you meaning by "fetching buckets" by prefix? It seems to me that you confuse buckets with object. Keep in mind that Gloud Storage does not have notion of directory. In Cloud Storage a directory is just by convention an object with a name containing its path sperated by '/'. I think what you want is calling [Objects.list](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) with a prefix parameter.

Comment: A prefix parameter would be nice. Wildcard would be better. The question is: how?  I updated the comment and clarified the use case.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm crazy. I was looking at the /buckets/ documentation, and instead I should have been looking at the /objects/ documentation.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list